# Updating column values in sequence with PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table named service. It has 10 rows and 4 columns. All columns and rows were filled but first column named num values are empty.

So I wanted to fill the num column with numbering order(1,2..10) for 10 rows by using PL/SQL Program.

Please anyone help me.

Comment: look for row_num()

Comment: Does the ordering matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

update service set num=rownum;